# ASP.Net with Jquery/ Javascript : Getting Error : {"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, pagemethods

We have migrated our ASP.Net Application to .Net version 4.6.2. Application uses javascript, Jquery for client validations and few value bindings.

We have published our code to our DEV server and Test server (site1), we faced no issue. When the same code is published in the same Test Server with another site (site2), we are facing an issue in loading 'PageMethods' methods from js files.

We are getting below error in site2:

> Error:Some exception occured-{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

because of which, some dropdowns are not being populated as the binding methods are in js.

Any idea, why this issue is? Please note, we have the same code in all the 3 published site/s:-
DEV server, Test server - site1 and site2.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please provide more details of the exception you are facing

Comment: With no error information, it is hard to tell what's going on. Have you tried including the pdb-files with your deployed site? Or are you manually removing the stack trace?

Comment: Since code is published in the test server, no chance i can make changes in web.config to make the customErrors as false. But when I tried debugging the same from IE browser and in the logs, i see this Error -
>Error:Some exception occured-{"Message":"There was an error 
processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

Comment: @Silvermind - no, pdb files are not included in the deployed site.

Comment: @Silvermind , tried with pdb files in the deployed site, no luck!

Answer (score 0):

capture the fiddler trace and see all the resources required for the page are available on the client side. you can also compare working and non working trace for more help.